# Android: Grid ViewPager with circular indication

Tags: android, gridview, android-viewpager

i'm trying to implement Grid ViewPager with circular indication. For this i spent lot of examples but i didn't get proper solution. I need the implementation as shown in the images

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STXq8.png), [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfalN.png)

As the attached images, i have to implement the Grid ViewPager with 5 swipeable pages. Thank you....

Comment: instand of Gridview use Viewpager

Comment: http://www.androprogrammer.com/2015/06/view-pager-with-circular-indicator.html